# The type Gallery is deprecated

Tags: android

```
imageView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

What are the other methods to replace Gallery. So I can use a horizontal scrolling in activity

Comment: Or a horizontal scrolling ListView.

Comment: [check this library](http://androidcustomviews.com/portfolio/two-way-gridview/) may be it helps you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Gallery](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html) documentation says:

> This widget is no longer supported. Other horizontally scrolling widgets include HorizontalScrollView and ViewPager from the support library.

The best way for you is to use `ViewPager` with an `ImageView` in its fragment layout.

You can see this sample [Android Gallery](https://github.com/Dreddik/AndroidTouchGallery) (No longer supported). There are also other gallery implementations on [GitHub](https://github.com).