# Slide Images into the view Like a gallery in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, horizontalscrollview

I want to show fixed number of `images (say 3)` in the first page of my app, like a gallery. Using a timer I download new image every minute. This image should slide in from right moving the existing images to the left. This means the first image disappears from the screen, new image appears as the last. Its better if the disappeared image gets disposed.

***Questions***

1. I want the images to adapt to the screen size so that for any screen size I can show 3 images always.
2. I tried using Horizontal scroll view, although I can add views, I could not find a way to remove the disappeared view while maintaining proper scroll locations.

whats the best way to do this. Is using `animations` the better way?

Thanks

Comment: You can use `HorizontalScrollView`.

Comment: thanks, I tried that, but cant maintain the location properly. I removed the disappearing one and added the new one, but scrolling didn't continue.

Answer (score 0):

You can Try this way

```
public class ImageDisplay extends Activity{
String image_url;
private Gallery gallery;
ArrayList<String>image_list=new ArrayList<String>();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.image_display);

    Intent in=getIntent();
    image_url=in.getExtras().getString("image_url");
    image_list = in.getStringArrayListExtra("all_image_url");


    gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.Gallery);     
    gallery.setAdapter(new MainActivity().new AddImgAdp(ImageDisplay.this,image_list.toArray(new String[image_list.size()])));

}
}
```

OUTPUT

[image]

Comment: Gallery is deprecated i guess
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18953047/the-type-gallery-is-deprecated